# How can I output unique, count and sum using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I need to find the unique, count and sum for the following data. I request your help.

```
08/2009   I-111   300
08/2009   I-112   400
08/2009   I-113   500
10/2009   I-200   1000
10/2009   I-300   500
11/2009   I-300   100
11/2009   I-100   400
```

So I need to find like this

```
08/2009 3 1200
10/2009 2 1500
```

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: And where is this data? File, DB? Please add some more info so we can help out.

Comment: What happened to 11/2009?  Should that not be output as well?

Answer (score 2):

`uniq` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils#uniq-LIST) returns the unique elements of a list:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';
my @x = uniq 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4;    # (1,2,3,5,4)
```

A list expression in scalar context returns the number of elements.

```
my @array = (5,6,7,8);
my $a_count = @array;       # 4

my %hash = ('x' => 1, 'y' => 2);
my $h_count = keys %hash;   # 2
```

`sum` from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil#sum-LIST) adds the elements of a list.

```
use List::Util 'sum';
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5);
print sum @array;   # 15
```

Comment: Since `Scalar::Util` is one of core modules, looks like other way is to tag your question `homework` at first :)

Comment: To be clear, the modules are 'List::Util' (singular) and 'List::MoreUtils' (plural).  The former was added to the Perl core in 5.7.3; the latter is **not** part of the core distribution.  'Scalar::Util' is yet another core module from 5.7.3 but handles things other than sums and finding unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want exactly, but is this ok?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my %h;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @el = split;
    $h{$el[0]}{count}++;
    $h{$el[0]}{sum} += $el[2];
}
dump%h;

__DATA__
08/2009   I-111   300
08/2009   I-112   400
08/2009   I-113   500
10/2009   I-200   1000
10/2009   I-300   500
11/2009   I-300   100
11/2009   I-100   400
```

**output:**

```
(
  "08/2009",
  { count => 3, sum => 1200 },
  "11/2009",
  { count => 2, sum => 500 },
  "10/2009",
  { count => 2, sum => 1500 },
)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for help. But my Perl compiler cannot locate Data::Dump.

Comment: `cpan Data::Dump`, but thats just for visualization, you can use `Data::Dumper` which is a core module, its use is like `use Data::Dumper; ... ; print Dumper(\%h);`

Answer (score 0):

Re: M42's answer, try:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h;
```

Or you could just write:

```
while (my ($key, $values) = each %h) {
    print "$key $values->{count} $values->{sum}\n";
}
```

Comment: Or if you use awk, it's as simple as: `awk '{count[$1]++;sum[$1]++} END {for (value in count) {print value,sum[value],count[value]}}' data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I don't do *Write my program for free* type stuff, but since [M42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/m42) already did most of it, here's it is without the `Data::Dump`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @el = split;
    $h{$el[0]}->{count}++;
    $h{$el[0]}->{sum} += $el[2];
}

foreach my $element (sort keys %h) {
    printf "%-10.10s  %-6.6s  %4d\n", $element, 
    $h{$element}->{count}, $h{$element}->{sum};
}
__DATA__
08/2009   I-111   300
08/2009   I-112   400
08/2009   I-113   500
10/2009   I-200   1000
10/2009   I-300   500
11/2009   I-300   100
11/2009   I-100   400
```

Now [learn yourself some Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001322.do)!

Comment: Hi Thaks all for your response. When I am working I am getting my output as follows which is bizaare! I am using Solaris unix. When I run the code on Ubunu it gave me correct values: Could u explian me or correct me please? My output is 1/2009 ==========> 38821
 01/2010 ==========> 32888 1/2209 ===>3
 01/2011 ==========> 27134
which supposed to be

Comment: @user1016594 What version of Perl is on your Ubuntu box and on Solaris. My code should work with almost any version of Perl after 5.x. I'm not using anything that wasn't first introduced since version 5.x. To find the perl version run `perl -v`.