# unique, count and sum values in perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, perl-data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I output unique, count and sum using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916855/how-can-i-output-unique-count-and-sum-using-perl)

How can I get unique, count and sum values in perl? My code is as follows:

```
   while (<$input>) {
               chomp;
               my($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16,$f17,$f18,$f19,$f20,$f21,$f22,$f23,$f24,$f25) = split(/\|/);
             $f24  = " " if !defined($f24);

             push @ff4, qw($f4); # VEN 10/19/11

             push @fff4, $f4, $f16, $f7; # VEN 10/28/11
             ..... ....... ...... ........ ......
             ..... ....... ...... ....... .......
    my %count;
    map { $count{$_} ++ } @array;
    my@count = map { "$_ ==========> ${count{$_}}\n"} sort keys (%count);

    #print $output2 sprintf("@count\n");


    my %h;
    my @el;
    while (<@array>)
                    {
                      $h{$el[0]}{count}++;
                      $h{ $el[0]}{sum} += $el[2];
                    }

    print $output2 %h;
```

I am getting output like this

```
       08/2009 ====> 2030
       08/2010 ====> 2300
       09/2010 =====> 1500
```

But I have to get it like this:

```
      08/2009 ====> 2
      08/2010 ====> 3
      09/2010 =====> 5
```

I am using Perl on Solaris

Comment: Can you please post WORKING code? `@array` is never assigned to before you use it in `map`

Comment: Why `my($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8,$f9,$f10,$f11,$f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16,$f17,$f18,$f19,$f20,$f21,$f22,$f23,$f24,$f25) = split(/\|/);`? Why not simply create an array? `@f = $_`. Then, you can use `$f[23]` instead of `$f24`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code doesn't work at all. We can't tell you how to fix it if you only post disjoint unrelated chunks.
2. To get unique elements of array, use [`List::MoreUtil`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils) module's `uniq()` method.

   To count them, use `scalar(@array)` or simply put an array into scalar context.

   To sum them up, use [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) module's `sum()` method
3. If you don't want to use standard CPAN modules, you can use a `foreach` loop:

   ```
   my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4);
   my %unique = map { $_ => 1 } @array; # keys will be unique now
   my @unique = sort keys %unique;
   my $count = scalar(@unique);
   my $sum = 0;
   $sum += $_ foreach @unique;
   ```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your email. But ur code is giving count as 6. But I want count as 1-->2, 2-1,3-1,4-2 Pl.help me out.Thanks